# How to put array response into input box?

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

Hi i needed help off putting an array into the input box value display below

This is how my array response is

```
[{"CollectionFirstDate": "2021-12-15", "StartDay": 1, "EndDay": 6}]
```

I woud like that this array is put into my input box

```
2021-12-15 = DateoffirstcollectionDisplay
StartDay": 1, "EndDay": 6  = dayrange
```

How can i do that ?

```html
<div class="mb-3 StyleFormRestRight dateoffirstcollection">
  <label for="CollectionType" class="col-3 form-label"><b class="Dateoffirstcollection">Date of first collection</b></label>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" class="col-2 form-control" id="DateoffirstcollectionDisplay" disabled readonly>
</div>

<div class="mb-3 StyleFormRestRight daysrange">
  <label for="CollectionType" class="col-3 form-label"><b class="dayrange">Day range</b></label>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" class="col-2 form-control" id="dayrange" disabled readonly>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your question asking how to set the input text? If you just use VanillaJS, e.g. `document.getElementById('dayrange').value='some value' ; `

Comment: yes correct how to set the array response to input value

Comment: Then you can do it with the example I wrote above. It is worth noting that because the response object is an array, you should pay attention when setting the value, eg `const datas = [{"CollectionFirstDate": "2021-12-15", " StartDay": 1, "EndDay": 6}]; ` `document.getElementById('dayrange').value= "" + datas[0]['StartDay']} + "-" +datas[0]['EndDay'] ;`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention any errors you've got. You may try this code:

```js
const responses = [
  { CollectionFirstDate: '2021-12-15', StartDay: 1, EndDay: 6 },
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  responses.forEach((response) => {
    document.getElementById('DateoffirstcollectionDisplay').value =
      response.CollectionFirstDate;
    document.getElementById(
      'dayrange'
    ).value = `${response.StartDay} - ${response.EndDay}`;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="mb-3 StyleFormRestRight dateoffirstcollection">
  <label for="CollectionType" class="col-3 form-label"
    ><b class="Dateoffirstcollection">Date of first collection</b></label
  >
  <br />
  <input
    type="text"
    class="col-2 form-control"
    id="DateoffirstcollectionDisplay"
    disabled
    readonly
  />
</div>

<div class="mb-3 StyleFormRestRight daysrange">
  <label for="CollectionType" class="col-3 form-label"
    ><b class="dayrange">Day range</b></label
  >
  <br />
  <input
    type="text"
    class="col-2 form-control"
    id="dayrange"
    disabled
    readonly
  />
</div>
```